# build dynamic sql insert query to merge multiple tables into single table using mapping table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, dynamic-sql

I am looking to take data from multiple mysql tables with different structures and insert it into one master table containing different columns/data from the sources,

I have created a column name mapping table with the following data:

### TABLE: affiliate_datafeed_magento_mapping

```
+----+-------------+----------------+
| id | datafeed    | magento        |
+----+-------------+----------------+
|  1 | SKU         | sku            |
|  1 | Name        | name           |
|  1 | Description | description    |
|  1 | Url         | affiliate_link |
|  1 | Price       | price          |
|  1 | Brand       | brand          |
|  1 | ModelNumber | model          |
|  2 | SKU         | sku            |
|  2 | Name        | name           |
|  2 | Description | description    |
|  2 | Url         | affiliate_link |
|  2 | Price       | price          |
|  2 | Currency    | affiliate_cur  |
+----+-------------+----------------+
```

`id` corresponds to the id of the affiliate program in the table `affiliate_programs`

`datafeed` corresponds the column name in the source table with the corresponding id in the table `affiliate_program`

`magento` corresponds the the column name in the table to receive the data

### TABLE: affiliate_programs

```
+----+-------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+
| id | affiliate_network | affiliate_network_short | affiliate_program      | affiliate_program_long | affiliate_program_short | affiliate_program_datafeed_url                                                                                                                                                        | affiliate_program_datafeed_csv_filename | affiliate_program_datafeed_last_get | order |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | CommissionFactory | cf_                     | Lifestyle Clotheslines | lifestyleclotheslines  | lcl                     | http://dashboard.commissionfactory.com.au/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/jPuB5NPigbec7prnjLCX5MHygO$A5sTlhOHb8t3nmufzta@k5uyn5qqxrLDr86GysLTj$bTyoKaj77Pltfmh9dvnkOCS4MHzjvTSlK6Dfg==/ | cf_lifestyleclotheslines.csv            | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
|  2 | CommissionFactory | cf_                     | MacArthur Baskets      | macarthurbaskets       | mcb                     | http://dashboard.commissionfactory.com.au/Affiliate/Creatives/DataFeeds/jPSA4dbg17SY7svvjeSX5Jf1iO@b5JXshOfY@ovjzeKj4PGivuyn5qqxrLDr86GysLTj$bTyoKaj77Pltfmh9dvnkOCS4MHzjvTSlK6Dfg==/ | cf_macarthurbaskets.csv                 | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
|  3 | ClixGalore        | cg_                     | Boutique Wineries      | boutiquewineries       | btw                     | http://www.is1.clixGalore.com/DataFileRequest.aspx?AdID=9522&AfID=264058                                                                                                              | cg_boutiquewineries.csv                 | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
|  4 | ClixGalore        | cg_                     | Brewtopia              | brewtopia              | bwt                     | http://www.is1.clixGalore.com/DataFileRequest.aspx?AdID=4817&AfID=264058                                                                                                              | cg_brewtopia.csv                        | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
|  5 | ClixGalore        | cg_                     | MacArthur Baskets      | macarthurbaskets       | mcb2                    | http://www.is1.clixGalore.com/DataFileRequest.aspx?AdID=4909&AfID=264058                                                                                                              | cg_macarthurbaskets.csv                 | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
|  6 | ClixGalore        | cg_                     | Winemakers Choice      | winemakerschoice       | wmc                     | http://www.is1.clixGalore.com/DataFileRequest.aspx?AdID=4282&AfID=264058                                                                                                              | cg_winemakerschoice.csv                 | 2013-08-12 22:23:02                 |  NULL |
+----+-------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------+
```

`id` corresponds to the same `id` in the table `affiliate_datafeed_magento_mapping`

the concatenation of `affiliate_programs.affiliate_network_short` and `affiliate_programs.affiliate_program_long` make up the name of the source table

### TABLE: cf_lifestyleclotheslines

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| id | DateCreated         | DateModified        | SKU  | Name                                                 | Category                                                                       | Description                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | Url                                                    | OriginalUrl                                                                                       | Image                                                             | Image50                                                                 | Image100                                                                  | Image120                                                                  | Image200                                                                  | Image300                                                                  | Image400                                                                  | Price        | Brand       | ModelNumber |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2012-10-19 10:52:50 | 2013-06-20 02:07:37 | 30   | Airaus Ceiling Mounted Clothes Airer                 | Home & Garden > Household Supplies > Laundry Supplies > Drying Racks & Hangers | Watch the Product Video            Just arrived from Europe!  Lifestyle Clotheslines is now stocking the latest ceiling mounted clothes airers from Europe.  Ceiling mounted clothes airers are the perfect alternative for those with limited space situations or who need the benefit of an indoor clothesline or airer.  Boasting 6 individually adjustable drying rods which are made of steel not plastic, these indoor airers can be used in a range of situations and are ideally suited for the disabled as they can easily be lowered or raised to the height of the user.  An indoor airer can also help extend the life of your clothes by reducing the exposure to harsh UV rays and they can also be a big power saver for your home when used to dry your washing instead of a tumble dryer.  Discover today how one of our new ceiling mounted clothes airers can save you money and take all the hard work and fuss out of drying your washing.      &nbsp;    //           Customer Video Reviews  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp... | https://track.commissionfactory.com.au/p/10604/1718691 | http://www.lifestyleclotheslines.com.au/airaus-ceiling-mounted-clothes-airer/                     | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@50x50.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@100x100.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@120x120.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@200x200.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@300x300.jpg | http://content.commissionfactory.com.au/Products/7228/1718691@400x400.jpg | 99.0000 AUD  |             | AIRAUS      |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

So with the data provided I'm looking to go through all the tables (concatenation of `affiliate_programs.affiliate_network_short` and `affiliate_programs.affiliate_program_long` columns in `affiliate_programs` and build a insert query for them all based on the mapped columns in the table `affiliate_datafeed_magento_mapping` to insert the data into the table `magento_export`

Any assistance would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Tim
I dont think you need the mapping table at all

I would use a series of `UNION` queries. One query per source. In the SELECT clause for each of those queries you should have a 1:1 column for each coulmn in your destination table, including mapping the value `NULL` where that destination column is not applicable to that source. (This is where the mapping really happens)

Then your INSERT statement is a straight-forward mapping of all the UNIONED queries into the destination table.

Pseudo code

```
INSERT INTO Destination(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT  T1.Field1 as Col1
        ,NULL as Col2
        ,T1.Field7 as Col3
        ,T1.Field2 as Col4
FROM    FirstSource T1
UNION
SELECT  T2.Field1 as Col1
        ,Some Calulation as Col2
        ,T2.Field3 as Col3
        ,NULL as Col4
FROM    FirstSource T1
```